# Using `extern template` to prevent implicit instantiation of a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, extern

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template <typename>
struct X { };

extern template struct X<int>;

int main()
{
    X<int>{};
}
```

It compiles and links: [**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Na5kZx). I would expect it not to link due to the `extern template` declaration.

My understanding is that `extern template` means: *"please don't instantiate this particular template specialization in this TU, it will be provided by some other TU and you can link against it"*.

The examples/descriptions. I've seen on *isocpp* and *cppreference* seem to validate my mental model. E.g.

> From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template:
>
> > An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) skips implicit instantiation step: **the code that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation instead uses the explicit instantiation definition provided elsewhere (resulting in link errors if no such instantiation exists)**. This can be used to reduce compilation times by explicitly declaring a template instantiation in all but one of the source files using it, and explicitly defining it in the remaining file.

**Why does my code snippet link? What is actually happening here?**

---

EDIT - found this in the latest Standard draft:

> [[temp.explicit]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#:instantiation,explicit)
>
> > If an entity is the subject of both an explicit instantiation declaration and an explicit instantiation definition in the same translation unit, the definition shall follow the declaration. **An entity that is the subject of an explicit instantiation declaration and that is also used in a way that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation in the translation unit shall be the subject of an explicit instantiation definition somewhere in the program; otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.**

Does this mean that the code snippet I posted is **ill-formed, NDR**?

Comment: @ittorio Romeo Looks like ill-formed because the explicit instantiation definition is absent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does my code snippet link? What is actually happening here?

Well, there's nothing *to* link. For one has to consider the effects of the explicit instantiation. From n3337:

> **[temp.explicit]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.explicit#10) **Except for inline functions and class template
>   specializations**, explicit instantiation declarations have the effect
>   of suppressing the implicit instantiation of the entity to which they
>   refer. [ Note: The intent is that an inline function that is the
>   subject of an explicit instantiation declaration will still be
>   implicitly instantiated when odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) so that the
>   body can be considered for inlining, but that no out-of-line copy of
>   the inline function would be generated in the translation unit. — end
>   note ]

So the implicit instantiation of the class template specialization `X<int>`, is not suppressed. It's also an aggregate, so its initialization occurs inline, and we get nothing to link against. However, if it had any members, those *would* be suppressed under paragraph [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.explicit#8):

> An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization
>   is also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or
>   definition) of each of its members (not including members inherited
>   from base classes) that has not been previously explicitly specialized
>   in the translation unit containing the explicit instantiation, except
>   as described below.

So if you had instead of an aggregate something akin to this:

```
template <typename>
struct X {
    X();
};

template <typename T>
X<T>::X() {}     

extern template struct X<int>;

int main()
{
    X<int>{};
}
```

That would fail as you expect, since it ODR uses a constructor whose definition is never instantiated. The declaration *is* instantiated, because the enclosing specialization is instantiated, as mentioned above. But we never get any definition, under the suppressing effect of the explicit instantiation declaration.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - If memory serves, godbolt doesn't do linkage, it only deals in object files. I originally tested on wandbox, see here https://wandbox.org/permlink/B6BVGqZWQJ4ACb4I

Comment: ah, thanks. I managed to reproduce it locally as well. Cheers. Is this answer in contrast with T.C.'s one, or am I missing something?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - It was prior to editing, and I hope it isn't anymore. T.C. is of course correct. I just wanted to point out that when it comes to ODR-violations it's most obvious when there's something linkable. IMO you should accept T.C.'s, since it's straight and to the point.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this mean that the code snippet I posted is ill-formed, NDR?

Yes, by the exact sentence from [temp.explicit]/13 that you quoted. "An entity" means just that. It does not matter if an explicit instantiation declaration otherwise have no normative effect.

Comment: So "subject of" is in the purely syntactical sense of the word?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. The note immediately following the sentence explains why this is the case for inline functions, another case where the explicit instantiation declaration has no other normative effect.

Comment: Premisse A : *An entity that is the subject of an explicit instantiation declaration*. Premisse B: * that is also used in a way that would **otherwise** cause an implicit instantiation in the translation unit". A is clearly true. The implicit instantiation of `class X` is not suppressed by the explicit instantiation declaration. I checked in the oxford dictionary for "otherwise", it clearly excludes from the set that it qualifies those elements that verifies the negation of the proposition: *the collection is a good draw that brings visitors who might not come otherwise*,

Comment: the collection does not bring visitors that would come without it. So Premisse B only applies to entities whose instantiation are suppressed by the explicit instantiation declaration. This is not the case of class template. So Premisse B is wrong in this case. So, as it is written, the conclusion of the paragraph you refers to should not apply.